# Store the contents of a pair of brackets/parenthises in a variable

Tags: javascript, for-loop, conditional-statements

In some variable called a, I want to store the contents of a pair of brackets from a variable called equation. I have an array called opening which marks the index of the opening brackets.

```
let equation = '2(x(4-5x)(4-x))+10'
let opening = [9,3,1,0]
let a = ''
```

### Attempt 1

```
    for(let x = equation[opening[0]]; x != ')'; x++) {
    a += x;
    }
```

this lead to an infinite loop.

### Attempt 2

```
    for(let x = equation[opening[0]]; x < equation.length; x++) {
        if (x == ')') {break;}
        a += x;
    }
```

this did not lead to an infinite loop but the variable a remained an empty string.

I want the result to be `a = ‘4-x’`

Comment: What do you mean with *store*? Could you show what the expected result should look like?

Comment: Ok yeah I edited my post, check the end please.

Comment: Could you also show what the output is supposed to look like for when you run it with opening[2]?  It looks like it will need to account for internal segments like counting opening parentheses, so it stops at the correct closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

Alright.  This was fun enough that I wrote an HTML page with JavaScript...

https://highdex.net/parse_eq.htm

You can view the source and see all the code, but in case I ever take that page down, I'll put just the JavaScript function in here too...

```
//this function takes an equation and breaks it into parts based on parentheses.
//it returns an array of the parts, where and equation like "4 * (8 - 1) / 4" would come back like...
//    index 0: "4 * [1] / 4"
//    index 1: "8 - 1"
//Any number shown in brackets is a reference to the index that holds what goes in that place, so you can rebuild the equation if you want.
function parseEquation(srcEq) {
    let parts = [""];
    let nextIndex = 0; //holds the next index we'll use inside those brackets
    let currentIndex = 0; //holds the current index we're adding characters to
    let backToArray = [0]; //holds the index that we need to go back to when the parentheses close
    let srcLen = srcEq.length;
        
    for (let i = 0; i < srcLen; i++) {
        let currentChar = srcEq[i];
            
        if (currentChar == "(") { //in this case we need to put the placeholder into the current index that references the next index, and then bump up the current index
            if (parts.length -1 < currentIndex) {
                parts.push("");
            }
            nextIndex++;
            parts[currentIndex] += "[" + nextIndex + "]";
            backToArray.push(currentIndex);
            currentIndex = nextIndex;
        }
        else if (currentChar == ")") { //in this case we need to drop the current char back down a level
            currentIndex = backToArray.pop();
        }
        else { //in this case we just add the current character to the current array at the current index
            if (parts.length -1 < currentIndex) {
                parts.push("");
            }
            
            parts[currentIndex] += currentChar;
        }
            
    }
        
    return parts;
}
```

Comment: This is very insightful, i am starting to understand your code at first i was so surprised at how we have similar variable names and what you've implemented is what i am actually aiming for. i am a newbie but im very impressed thank you Kevin!

Answer (score 0):

Put the a+= x in the brackets before break

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).